# how to tokenize big text in sentences and words

Tags: python, nltk, tokenize

I'm working with nltk in language portuguese.

That's is my text:

```
import numpy as np 
from nltk.corpus import machado, mac_morpho, floresta, genesis

from nltk.text import Text
ptext1 = Text(machado.words('romance/marm05.txt'), name="Memórias Póstumas de Brás Cubas (1881)")
ptext2 = Text(machado.words('romance/marm08.txt'), name="Dom Casmurro (1899)")
ptext3 = Text(genesis.words('portuguese.txt'), name="Gênesis")
ptext4 = Text(mac_morpho.words('mu94se01.txt'), name="Folha de Sao Paulo (1994)")
```

Per exemple,  i want to divide the ptext4 in sentences and after i want to divide  in words:

```
sentencas = nltk.sent_tokenize(ptext4)
palavras = nltk.word_tokenize(ptext4)
```

But it doesn't work: The error is expected string or bytes-like object

I tryed this:

```
sentencas = [row for row in nltk.sent_tokenize(row)]
```

But the result isen't  the expectate:

```
[In]sentencas
[Out] ['Fujimori']
```

what can i do, please? I'm new in that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want the list of words from the `machado` corpus, use the `.words()` function.

```
>>> from nltk.corpus import machado
>>> machado.words()
```

But if you want to process raw text, e.g.

```
>>> text = machado.raw('romance/marm08.txt')
>>> print(text)
```

Use this idiom

```
>>> from nltk import word_tokenize, sent_tokenize
>>> text = machado.raw('romance/marm08.txt')
>>> tokenized_text = [word_tokenize(sent) for sent in sent_tokenize(text)]
```

And to iterate through the `tokenized_text`, which is a `list(list(str))`, do this:

```
>>> for sent in tokenize_text:
...     for word in sent:
...         print(word)
...     break
...
```

Comment: Also, please do take a look at https://www.kaggle.com/alvations/basic-nlp-with-nltk

Comment: Thanks, your answer helped me as well.
I did it after your answer and it was possible to get word tokenize and sentence tokenize of the text:

from nltk import word_tokenize, sent_tokenize
text = machado.raw('romance/marm08.txt')
tokenized_words = [word_tokenize(sent) for sent in sent_tokenize(text)]
tokenized_sents = [sent_tokenize(text)]

Answer (score 1):

```
word_token  =  list(pytext1)  # if you want to have only word token from pytext1
print(word_token[0:10]) # printing first 10 token

#op
['Romance',',','Memórias','Póstumas','de','Brás','Cubas',',','1880','Memórias'] 

#if you want sent_token of text using sent_tokenize, read textfile in raw form 
raw_text = machado.raw('romance/marm05.txt')

print(raw_text[0:100]) # printing first 100 character from sentence
#op
'Romance, Memórias Póstumas de Brás Cubas, 1880\n\nMemórias Póstumas de\nBrás Cubas\n\nTexto-fonte:\nObra C'

sent_token = nltk.sent_tokenize(raw_text)
print(sent_token[0:2]) # printing 2 sentence, which is tokenized from text

['Romance, Memórias Póstumas de Brás Cubas, 1880\n\nMemórias Póstumas de\nBrás 
Cubas\n\nTexto-fonte:\nObra Completa, Machado de\nAssis,\nRio\nde Janeiro: Editora 
Nova Aguilar, 1994.',
'Publicado originalmente em\nfolhetins, a partir de março de 1880, na Revista Brasileira.']
```

Comment: I needed by tokenize words and tokenize sentences. 
i did it after your answer: 

word_token = nltk.word_tokenize(raw_text)
sent_token = nltk.sent_tokenize(raw_text)
print(sent_token[0:2]) # printing 2 sentence, which is tokenized from text
print(word_token[0:20])

Then, i guess got it how to tokenize setences and words in a text. 
Thanks for helped me.

Answer (score 0):

Then, there are two ways to go answer this question according @qaiser and @alvas. both answers solve the problem in different ways.
The second answer has minus rows of code:

```
import numpy as np 
from nltk.corpus import machado
import nltk

#if you want sent_token of text using sent_tokenize, read textfile in raw form 
raw_text = machado.raw('romance/marm05.txt')


word_token = nltk.word_tokenize(raw_text)
sent_token = nltk.sent_tokenize(raw_text)

[In]:print(sent_token[0:2]) # printing 2 sentence, which is tokenized from text
[Out]: ['Romance, Memórias Póstumas de Brás Cubas, 1880\n\nMemórias Póstumas de\nBrás Cubas\n\nTexto-fonte:\nObra Completa, Machado de\nAssis,\nRio\nde Janeiro: Editora Nova Aguilar, 1994.', 'Publicado originalmente em\nfolhetins, a partir de março de 1880, na Revista Brasileira.']

[In]:print(word_token[0:20]) # printing 20 words, wich is tokenized from text
[Out]:['Romance', ',', 'Memórias', 'Póstumas', 'de', 'Brás', 'Cubas', ',', '1880', 'Memórias', 'Póstumas', 'de', 'Brás', 'Cubas', 'Texto-fonte', ':', 'Obra', 'Completa', ',', 'Machado']
```